# Sempron 3600+ SSE instructions missing. DirectX 11 not installing

Tags: windows-7, cpu, gpu, directx-11

I have run CPU-Z but no SSE1/2/3 were found under the instruction set. My GPU is an ATI Radeon HD5450. I haven't over-clocked the GPU or the CPU. This is the CPU-Z report:

[image: CPU-Z]

When I try to web-update DirectX 11 it stops installation, a message occurs (the one with windows logs in it) and alerts me for the missing SSE instruction set.

Everest tells me I have DirectX 9c installed. But as I try to play a newer game (that requires DX11), crashes.

I did defrag, clean the Registry, Complete system scan, reinstalled everything related to the problem. The only thing I'm not able to do is to flash the BIOS. For Everest the problem may be this.

The following is the Everest report:

> CPUID Properties: CPUID Manufacturer AuthenticAMD CPUID CPU Name AMD Sempron(tm) Processor 3600+ CPUID Revision 00040FF2h Extended CPUID Revision 00040FF2h Platform ID 00h (Unknown) IA CPU Serial Number Unknown HTT / CMP Units 0 / 0
>
> Instruction Set: 64-bit x86 Extension (AMD64, EM64T) Supported Alternate Instruction Set Not Supported AMD 3DNow! Supported AMD 3DNow! Professional Not Supported AMD Enhanced 3DNow! Supported AMD Extended MMX Supported Cyrix Extended MMX Supported IA-64 Not Supported IA MMX Supported IA SSE Not Supported IA SSE 2 Not Supported IA SSE 3 Not Supported CLFLUSH Instruction Supported CMPXCHG8B Instruction Supported CMPXCHG16B Instruction Supported Conditional Move Instruction Supported
>
> MONITOR / MWAIT Instruction Not Supported RDTSCP Instruction Supported SYSCALL / SYSRET Instruction Supported SYSENTER / SYSEXIT Instruction Supported VIA FEMMS Instruction Not Supported

The SSE instruction set is required for some installations such as Teamspeak and DirectX, so I think my CPU is broken because as I understodd every Sempron version has SSE1 at least.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sempron#Manila_.2890_nm_SOI.29) the Manilla processor has SSE 1/2/3; CPU-Z may just condense that as the x86-64 instruction set. And [your](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/ati-radeon-hd-5000/hd-5450-overview/Pages/hd-5450-overview.aspx#2) graphics board does support DirectX 11. Can you clarify what your problem was, adding the most **detail** you can?

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer.  Are you sure about the condensation? Seems a little awkward..  Yes as Everest tells me I have DirectX 9c installed. But as I try to play a newer game (that requires DX11), crashes. When I try to Install DX11 a message occurs  (the one with windows logs in it). I did defrag, clean Reg, Complete system scan, reinstalled everithing connected to the problem. The only think I'm not able to do is flash BIOS. For Everest the problem may be this.... How can I post the Everest report?

Comment: First of, it is better to edit your original post rather than adding this information inside comments. Second, you've been mentioning Everest... is that a game? If so, can you post a link to it? Other than this I can't see the relation your information has with your problem (that I'm assuming it is you are unable to install DirectX 11, but you **haven't made that clear yet**)

Comment: Can you post (or link a picture) of the error the DirectX 11 installation is giving you?